# How do I extract a .Z file in java?

Tags: java

I can extract the zip, tar, tar.gz and tar.bz in apache.commons.compress. But I can't extract the tar.Z in apache.commons.compress or java. Who can help me?

Comment: this might help: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compress - its an `LZC compression`

Comment: it seem that any libraries cover .Z files.

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/compress-j2me/

Answer (score 0):

The `tar.Z` extension means that the file is a compressed tarball, using the `compress` utility, not `gzip`.

The only library that seems to support it is: http://www.chilkatsoft.com/tar-java.asp

Hope this helps.